# Implement IPrincipal in winforms project

Tags: c#, winforms, forms-authentication

I'm trying to implement Authorization and Authentication in my current winforms project.  The Authentication also has to match a user in an SQL Server 2008 database.  The thing is, it's a multi-user program, so when a new user is added, a database is created and the users identity added to the database.

I wondered if that is possible implementing IPrincipal and IIdentity.  I've only found ASP.NET implementations so far.

Can anybody give me some guidance as to what's the best way to implement password/userid security in a winforms application?  Keeping in mind that it has to be verified with a database in SQL Server.

Meaning that a database has to exist for that user, and their credentials need to be correct.

Comment: How you authenticate users and how you subsequently represent authenticated users are two different things. Are you asking about how to implement IPrincipal, or how to authenticate users using a username/password mechanism?

Comment: I actually want to know how to authenticate users using psw/username?

Comment: Are you sure this is really what you want to do? Using a custom authentication mechanism for a rich client is a quite unusual thing to do. Normally, it is much better to rely on the built-in security mechanisms of Windows. Maybe we need a bit of context here. A kiosk-type application is one of the few examples I can think of where this would make sense.

Comment: My app is one to store data that needs to be secure, so I wanted to implement my own mechanism, but what has windows got to offer?  

I'm not sure what you mean with 'kiosk-type application'?

Comment: Well, for authentication, Windows has a log-on screen that ensures that the currently logged on user is correct. However, I must admit that I am still confused by your requirements, because now you are talking about storing sensitive data, which is a different goal than authenticating a user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement your own `IPrincipal` object by writing a class that implements that interface.

Since you are going to use a source other that Windows to provide username and password, you will also need to write your own `IIdentity` implementation as well.

Fortunately these are not large interfaces.

For your custom `IIdentity`, I would create a Login form that attempts to find a username/password combination in the SQL 2008 database.  If found, your only concern then is how to populate the "Roles" of that user to provide functionality for `IsInRole(string roleName)` method off the interface.

Here is a link to a [detailed article on how to accomplish in both Winforms and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163807.aspx)

**UPDATE**

Also, once you attach this principal to the Current Thread (and subsequent created threads), you can also add attributes to your code that "demand" the current Principal belongs to a given role, or has a given name.

A good [example of that is this](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/041208.htm) article.

Comment: @TonyTheLion - would you mind marking this Answer as Accepted?